# Bash script no response

Tags: bash

Cannot figure out why this will not run or provide any output. Trying to download some json files, but it's not doing anything. I have looked over it and don't see what I am doing wrong.

```
for i in $(seq 0 100); do wget "http://example.com/stats.json&id=${i}" -o "${i}.txt"; done
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong; try running `set -x` before it to see what the shell thinks is happening inside the loop.

Comment: That ampersand in the URL without a preceding question mark is a little suspicious...

Comment: @KJThaDon: Are the files `0.txt`, `1.txt` usw. empty afterwards or don't they exist?

Comment: Not sure what you mean @user1934428. They're not empty files.

Comment: If they are not empty, they contain the error messages and you might find the reason why the  `wget` failed.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now...The files never actually download. CMd opens and closes instantly